# Setting a column in a dataframe to new values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

def labelencoder(dataframe) : 
  label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
  dataframe= label_encoder.fit_transform(dataframe)
  
  return dataframe

new_df['label'] = labelencoder(new_df['label'])
```

I am getting the following warning for the above code:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>
> new_df['label'] = labelencoder(new_df['label'])

The code is working fine, it just shows this warning each time. Is there a solution?

I tried something like:

```py
new_df.loc[:, 'label'] = labelencoder(new_df['label'])
```

But it didn't work, It still shows the warning

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get rid off the `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```py
def labelencoder(df): 
  label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
  return label_encoder.fit_transform(df)

new_df.loc[:, 'label'] = labelencoder(new_df['label'])
```

When you set

```py
df = label_encoder.fit_transform(df)
```

inside your function, and calling the function with `new_df['label']` as argument, you are in fact doing the following:

```py
new_df['label'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(new_df['label'])
```

which is what gives you the warning.

To get rid of it, directly return the encoded label.

Comment: Should I call the function like this
   labelencoder(new_df['label']

Because it does not actually encode the values

Comment: @UserBen No, like this: `new_df.loc[:, 'label'] = labelencoder(new_df['label'])`

Answer (score -1):

Try using -

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

The potential for false positives is addressed in the [docs on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html).